# I'm not able to see radio button in iOS, android is fine in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I tried to add styling as well. but nothing is work.

iOS:

[image]

[image]

```
 <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,10" IsVisible="{Binding isShowRadioButton}">
                                                                       <StackLayout 
                                                                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding inspectionQuestionOption}">
                                                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="answersofradio">
                                                                                     <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" GroupName="Numbers"/>
                                                                                    <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding optionName}" TextColor="White"/>
                                                                                </StackLayout>
                                                                              
                                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                                      
                                                

                                                                </StackLayout>
```

Here is style that i've applied for radio button. so i've created control template and applied into style.

```
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
<Border Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Ellipse x:Name="border_circle" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderColor}" Fill="White" WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="check" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderColor}" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

can someone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This was a bug. Looks like it is fixed for an upcoming version https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13215

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue on the GitHub and you can refer to the [VisualStates for RadioButton not working](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12805). You can follow it up and ask for more information.

In addition, I found that this might be a workaround for this issue. Here is the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11747#issuecomment-1478664824) you can check.